# Vuetify Calendar hides events on build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

When I am in dev mode it shows all the events normally one above the other but when I run the build and start it, it does'nt show them like that or hides it, is there something I can do to prevent that to happen?

1. Showing the events correctly
   [image: Showing the events correctly]
2. Hides the events
   [image: Hides the events]

Comment: Not sure to understand the difference between both images.

Comment: In the first one the events are showed one above the other without eliminating or hiding anything, The second one is when i do de build to prod and start it, the events are shown next to each other and if an event is between those two, it hides instead of be on top or in the bottom thing that happens on dev mode.